# Converting list into matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, data-conversion

Suppose I have a list of numbers

```
L = [16, 5, 14, 7, 21, 9, 14, 19, 27, 1, 18, 5,27, 15, 14, 5, 27, 20, 15, 27, 15, 14, 5]
```

I want to convert `L` into 3x1 vectors until the whole L is used. We use 27 if not enough entries are there. And then we augment the vector to form a matrix.

How can I do that? Can someone please give a hint?

[image]

Comment: The first step is to specify how exactly you want the matrix to be represented in the code. As a nested list? As a numpy 2d array? As a numpy matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to convert each chunk of items into rows (in a list of lists, aka matrix):

```
L=[16, 5, 14, 7, 21, 9, 14, 19, 27, 1, 18, 5,27, 15, 14, 5, 27,
   20, 15, 27, 15, 14, 5]

rows,cols,fill = 3,8,27

M=[(L[c::rows]+[fill]*cols)[:cols] for c in range(rows)]

print(*M,sep="\n")

[16, 7, 14, 1, 27, 5, 15, 14]
[5, 21, 19, 18, 15, 27, 27, 5]
[14, 9, 27, 5, 14, 20, 15, 27]
```

*Note: this also works if you have fewer elements in the output matrix than in the source list (e.g. rows,cols=4,4)*

Comment: Thanks. How can I put 16, 5, 14 in row 1 and so on.. kindly see the attached image in OP

Comment: oh, it was column-wise, sry I missed that ... fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to keep it simple. If your length of the list is less than a multiple of 3. Just append it with 27s!. After that you can break it into 3 rows and remaining columns. Try this method -

1. Append the list with the number of 27s that make the list's length divisible by 3
2. Iterate and break list over chunks of length/3 = 8 in this case.

```
L=[16, 5, 14, 7, 21, 9, 14, 19, 27, 1, 18, 5,27, 15, 14, 5, 27, 20, 15, 27, 15, 14, 5]

L2 = L+[27]*(3-len(L)%3) #Append list
n = int(len(L2)/3)       #Get number of cols
L3 = [L2[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(L2),n)] #chunk list
L3
```

```
[[16, 5, 14, 7, 21, 9, 14, 19],
 [27, 1, 18, 5, 27, 15, 14, 5],
 [27, 20, 15, 27, 15, 14, 5, 27]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
L = [16, 5, 14, 7, 21, 9, 14, 19, 27, 1, 18, 5, 27, 15, 14, 5, 27, 20, 15, 27, 15, 14, 5]
v = 3

M = [[] for _ in range(v)]
r = 0
for i in L:
    M[r].append(i)
    r += 1
    if r == v:
        r = 0
```

Output:

```
[[16, 7, 14, 1, 27, 5, 15, 14],
 [5, 21, 19, 18, 15, 27, 27, 5],
 [14, 9, 27, 5, 14, 20, 15]]
```

Explanation:

1. Define a variable `v` to store the number of rows the matrix will have.
2. Define a list `M` consisting of `v` of empty lists.
3. Define a variable `i` to store th index of the row that will have another number appended to it.
4. Iterate through each value in the `L` list, and append the element into the `M` list at `i` index.
5. Increment the `i` index by `1` to advance to the next index, and revert its value back to `0` if the index reaches beyond the maximum index of `M`.